# Why is the volume of Torricelli's (Gabriel’s) trumpet finite?

Tags: geometry

I’m aware that Torricelli’s trumpet has a infinite surface area, but why does it have a finite volume?

Comment: You  can see interesting answers to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214357/intuition-behind-this-interesting-calculus-result/2214379#2214379

Comment: Gabriele Torricelli is his real name.

Comment: It's Evangelista Torricelli who studied Gabriel's Horn: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because
 $\int_1^{\infty} dx/x^2$
converges
while
 $\int_1^{\infty} dx/x$
diverges.

Answer (score 2):

> (...) but why does it have a finite volume?

Because the (improper) integral that we take as a model or definition of the (generalized) volume of this "unbounded object" is:
$$\pi\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mbox{d}x$$
and this integral is convergent; it has value $\pi$:
$$\pi\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mbox{d}x = \pi\lim_{k \to +\infty}\int_1^k \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mbox{d}x = \pi\lim_{k \to +\infty} \left[ -\frac{1}{x} \right]_1^k = \pi$$

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, imagine you have a cylinder with a constant volume, now if you reduce its radius and increase the height, it becomes a slimmer cylinder with a constant volume and larger surface area than the original cylinder. If you keep doing that you will get a cylinder with a finite volume and infinite surface area. This is what exactly happens to Torricelli’s trumpet.